# Select the direct children of an element and apply the function to them using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
     <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
     <p>test</p>
  </div>
 <div>
```

How can I select all direct div children with parent class and execute a function on them using addEventListener?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all of the divs, and then add the event listeners inside a loop.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > .child')
for (const div of divs) {
  div.addEventListener('...', () => {
    // ...
  })
}
```

Comment: You should declare your variables: `for (const div of divs)`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to select the child elements. For example by using querySelectorAll.

```js
const childs = document.querySelectorAll(".parent .child");

childs.forEach(c => c.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  alert();
}))
```

```html
<p>Click of one of the tests p tags!</p>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
     <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
     <p>test</p>
  </div>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Instead of adding listeners to *many* elements, add *one* to the parent and let it capture events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. The handler function can check what child element has been triggered, and then *<do something>* depending on that outcome.

In this example we're checking that the element that has been clicked on is a `p` element that is the child of an element with a `.child` class, and logging its text content.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.child p')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
}
```

```css
p:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Test 1 - will be logged</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Test 2 - will not be logged</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Test 3 - will be logged</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Test 4 - will not be logged</p>
  </div>
</div>
```